# Drawing multiple shapes using canvas like paint application

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a paint like application using canvas. I am able to draw with free hand tool but when i try to using shapes we need to use clearrect method which i am not able to use properly. I need to draw multiple shapes on canvas with mouse but unable to do so.

Here is a link to what i am trying 
http://jsfiddle.net/6vq64sdh/

HTML:

`<canvas width="800px" height="600px" id="drawing"></canvas>`

JS

```
var isDown;
var start;
var end;
var canvasEl = document.getElementById("drawing");
var draw = canvasEl.getContext("2d");
draw.lineWidth = "2";
draw.strokeStyle = "blue";
var lastWidth = 0;
var lastHeight = 0;

$("#drawing").mousedown(function(e) {
    isDown = true;
    start = getMousePos(canvasEl, e);
    end = getMousePos(canvasEl, e);
    lastWidth = 0;
    lastHeight = 0;
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#drawing").mouseup(function() {
    isDown = false;
});

$("#drawing").mousemove(function(e) {
    if (!isDown) return;
    var end = getMousePos(canvasEl, e);
    var h = end.y - start.y;
    var w = end.x - start.x;
    draw.clearRect(start.x-5, start.y-5, lastWidth + 6, lastHeight + 6);
    draw.beginPath();
    draw.rect(start.x, start.y, w, h);
    lastWidth = w;
    lastHeight = h;
    draw.stroke();
    draw.closePath();
});


function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: Math.floor(evt.clientX - rect.left),
        y: Math.floor(evt.clientY - rect.top)
    };
}
```

in above link able to draw multiple rectangles when i tried to drag mouse right side but unable to do when i drag it to left side. Could you please

Comment: Please post the code here, don't just link it

Comment: new here will try to do that in next questions..!!

Answer (score 1):

I have just a little bit improved your code. It looks like you having some trouble when you trying to draw new rectangle over an already exists one.

I make a variable that will store the drawed rectangles. (Its like browser's brain) And the bottom of code, i created a `setInterval()` function that re-draw your rectangles that in the brain variable in `60fps`.

```js
var drawed_objects = []; //our brain variable
    var isDown;
    var start;
    var end;
    var canvasEl = document.getElementById("drawing");
    var draw = canvasEl.getContext("2d");
    draw.lineWidth = "2";
    draw.strokeStyle = "blue";
    var lastWidth = 0;
    var lastHeight = 0;

    $("#drawing").mousedown(function(e) {
        isDown = true;
        start = getMousePos(canvasEl, e);
        end = getMousePos(canvasEl, e);
        lastWidth = 0;
        lastHeight = 0;
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#drawing").mouseup(function() {
      drawed_objects.push({start:start,width:w,height:h});
        isDown = false;
    });

    $("#drawing").mousemove(function(e) {
        if (!isDown) return;
        end = getMousePos(canvasEl, e);
        h = end.y - start.y;
        w = end.x - start.x;
        draw.clearRect(start.x-5, start.y-5, lastWidth + 6, lastHeight + 6);
        draw.beginPath();
        draw.rect(start.x, start.y, w, h);
        lastWidth = w;
        lastHeight = h;
        draw.stroke();
        draw.closePath();
    });

    //in here we drawing old rectangles again again again..
    //and all time clearing the canvas
    setInterval(function(){
      draw.clearRect(0,0,draw.canvas.width,draw.canvas.height);

      for( let i=0; i <drawed_objects.length; i++ )
      {
        var obj = drawed_objects[i];
        draw.beginPath();
        draw.rect(obj.start.x, obj.start.y, obj.width, obj.height);
        draw.stroke();
        draw.closePath();
      }

    },1000/60);

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: Math.floor(evt.clientX - rect.left),
            y: Math.floor(evt.clientY - rect.top)
        };
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="800px" height="600px" id="drawing"></canvas>
```